# Unknown component in schematics

Tags: transistors, schematics, esp32

I'm trying to interact with my Daikin AC and found these schematics. My electronics knowledge is pretty basic and I can't understand what kind of transistor is in the red circle... if it's a transistor :D

[image]

(the schematics is from [this post on the HA forum](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/daikin-integration-updated-2022-09-26/431819/26))

What kind of transistor is in the red circle?

Comment: I believe it's a transistor, but without clearer information, it's hard to confirm. If anyone can provide more details or insights, that would be helpful

Comment: And the D means the drain pin of the transistor.  The other two pins being the gate (G) and the source (S).  The usually schematic reference designator for a transistor is Q.

Comment: If you don't recognize a MOSFET then you shouldn't be meddling with this. Mains-powered electronics is dangerous if you don't know what you are doing. Start with something simpler and less expensive to destroy.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

That is an N-type mosfet with a current protection diode built in. It might be easier to understand if you think of it like two separate components, the Nfet and the diode. The purpose of the diode is to protect the Nfet against a large reverse current surge, which is usually caused by inductive loads like motors or transformers or inductors.

Comment: That's not a "current protection" diode. That's the built-in body diode, which is a consequence of how three-terminal MOSFETs are fabricated, and not always well-characterized or consistent in its performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Part identification is correct, but the description is not.